# Is there performance issues when using !important?

Tags: css

When I use a syntax editor, I always get notices about "use of `!important`" Is there some reason that I shouldn't use it? Is there performance issues or something with it?

Comment: No, there's no performance degraditions just debugging css becomes a pain

Answer (score 1):

Using !important is rarely needed, you should narrow down your CSS rather than override with `!important`. It will likely bite you in a large app with a lot of CSS
There really is no need for it. If you find yourself using `!important` you can probably get rid of it by being much more specific

e.g.
Given the following HTML

```
  <div id="cat-content>
    <p>
      The cat sat on the mat
    </p>
    <p>
      The cat and the fiddle
    </p>
  </div>

  <div id="dog-content>
    <p>
      The dog did bark to see such fun
    </p>
    <p>
      The dog ran away with the spoon
    </p>
  </div>
<p>
  Some more important text in black
</p>
```

Then with the following css

```
#cat-content p {
  color: blue;
}
#dog-content p {
  color: brown;
}
p{
  color: black;
}
p {
 color: red !important;
}
```

All text will be in red! You have just restyled every single paragraph text across the whole of your website with the colour red! No not really what you want? Just the cat content paragraphs to be red by styling specifically the paragraph tags in the cat div to have the text colour of red by just changing

```
#cat-content p {
  color: blue;
}
```

to

```
#cat-content p {
  color: red;
}
```

The need to use !important can often be because of complexity and the need to use this should be corrected before resorting to `!important` before you end up in an even bigger mess.

How would you restyle the just more important text to be red? By wrapping it in a div and styling it the same way as the other paragraphs

```
<div class="red-paragraphs">
  <p>
    Some more important text in black
  </p>
</div>
```

then style as so

```
.red-paragraphs p {
  color: red;
}
```

specificity is also important here and you really should read up on it. W3Schools has a great explanation here https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp

It says

> Note: Specificity is a common reason why your CSS-rules don't apply to
> some elements, although you think they should. Specificity Hierarchy
>
> Every selector has its place in the specificity hierarchy. There are
> four categories which define the specificity level of a selector:
>
> Inline styles - An inline style is attached directly to the element to
> be styled. Example: .
>
> IDs - An ID is a unique identifier for the page elements, such as
> #navbar.
>
> Classes, attributes and pseudo-classes - This category includes
> .classes, [attributes] and pseudo-classes such as :hover, :focus etc.
>
> Elements and pseudo-elements - This category includes element names
> and pseudo-elements, such as h1, div, :before and :after. How to
> Calculate Specificity?
>
> Memorize how to calculate specificity!
>
> Start at 0, add 1000 for style attribute, add 100 for each ID, add 10
> for each attribute, class or pseudo-class, add 1 for each element name
> or pseudo-element.
>
> Consider these three code fragments: Example A: h1 B: #content h1 C:
>
> Heading
>
> The specificity of A is 1 (one element) The specificity of B is 101
> (one ID reference and one element) The specificity of C is 1000
> (inline styling)
>
> Since 1 < 101 < 1000, the third rule (C) has a greater level of
> specificity, and therefore will be applied. Specificity Rules
>
> Equal specificity: the latest rule counts - If the same rule is
> written twice into the external style sheet, then the lower rule in
> the style sheet is closer to the element to be styled, and therefore
> will be applied:

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#The_!important_exception)

> Using `!important`, however, is **bad practice** and should be avoided because it makes debugging more difficult by breaking the natural cascading in your stylesheets.